# Create an IF statement in VBA for operating system

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create an IF statement to change a string depending on the operating system. Is this possible?

Idea:

```
Sub create_path()

Dim os_is_mac As Boolean
Dim slash As String

If os_is_mac Then
   slash = "/"
else: slash = "\"
End if

end sub
```

Comment: You need to close if statement with `End IF`.

Comment: Maybe `If InStr(Application.OperatingSystem, "Windows")>0 Then`

Comment: Shouldn't the `Application.PathSeparator` property take care of this and return the correct separator?

Comment: I didn't know about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like [this](https://www.excelvbasolutions.com/2015/10/detect-operating-system.html):

```vb
Sub create_path()

    Dim os_is_mac As Boolean
    Dim slash As String
    
    os_is_mac = Application.OperatingSystem Like "*Mac*"
    
    If os_is_mac Then
        slash = "/"
    Else
        slash = "\"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you!